# Navigation bar doesn't appear in uiviewtable in popupovercontrol

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have PopupoverControl and this popup has UIViewtablecontrol and one of UITable control should navigate to another UIViewtablecontrol but it doesn't navigate this is the code in selection in first uitableview:

```
OpenFileViewController *openfileview = [[OpenFileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenFileViewController" bundle:nil v_files:[self GetFiles] v_ui:parentview];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:openfileview];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

in .xib file in both uiviewtable I enabled Top Bar with Navigation Bar but it doesn't appear why?

Comment: did you set the delegates and all the connections? Simply dragging the navigation bar onto the xib doesnt connect it to your class.

Comment: do you mean this UITableViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the new `navController`, try this instead:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:openfileview animated:YES];
```

**Edit**:

The root view controller of the popover should be a `UINavigationController` object, so try this when you're creating the popover:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: optionw];
UIPopoverController *optioandiaglog= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
```

Comment: nothing work I watched videos but i can't find what is the problem is it because of the ipad ? all videos discuss it on iphone

Comment: `OptionsWindows *optionw = [[OptionsWindows alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsWindows" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] v_size:self.bounds.size v_ui:self];'

Comment: 'UIPopoverController *optioandiaglog= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:optionw];
    optionpopup = optioandiaglog;
    optionw->optionpopoverController = optionpopup;
    [optionpopup setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)]; 
    CGRect popoverRect = [self convertRect:[save_bt frame] 
                                  fromView:[save_bt superview]];
    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100); 
    [optionpopup presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

Comment: Well, the content view controller of the popover should be a `UINavigationController` object, so try this when you're creating the popover: `UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: optionw];
UIPopoverController *optioandiaglog= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];`